# For loop beginner understanding

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I am currently learning C and want to check if my understanding of the `for` loop is correct.

Does the output `A is 6` occur because after the 5th time the loop is run, the +1 is added to `a` (which makes it 6), and then the condition is stopped because it is no longer `<= 5` ?

```
int a;
float b;

b = 0;

for (a = 1; a <= 5; a++)
    b = b + 0.5;

printf ("A is %d\t\t B is %.2f\n", a, b);
```

Output is

```
A is 6       B is 2.50
```

Comment: Your assumptions are correct, use the `f` suffix for floats `b = b + 0.5f;`

Comment: @AlterMann should that be done for all float points ? Thanks

Comment: Only for  `float`, `0.5` without the suffix means `double`

Comment: Just for future reference : with `float` variables, it's not always the case that a loop executing `b += c` `n` times (where `c` is a constant, like here) will add `c * n` to `b`. But you shouldn't worry about this for now. Or should you...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

When `a == 5`, the condition `a <= 5` is true, so the body of the loop (`b = b + 0.5;`) is executed. After the body, the `a++` part is always executed.

This makes `a == 6`. Then the condition `a <= 5` is `false`, so the loop terminates.

It is occasionally useful to use the value of the index after the loop.

Comment: @NZSteve No worries. I remember being a little surprised the first time I saw `a == 6` even though the loop says `a <= 5`, but it makes sense when you think about it.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct.  The `for (init; condition; finish)` language feature is a convenience for a structure that looks like this:

```
init;
while (condition) {
    ...insert code here...
    finish;
}
```